# How do I use Perl's Inline::C?

Tags: perl, inline

I have a piece of code like this (Perl file):

```
print "9 + 16 = ", add(9, 16), "\n";
print "9 - 16 = ", subtract(9, 16), "\n";
```

C code also,

```
#include<stdio.h>

main ()
{
 int x = 9;
 int y = 16;
 printf(" add() is %d\n", add(x,y));
 printf(" sub() is %d\n", subtract(x,y));
//  return 0; 
}
int add(int x, int y) 
{
 return x + y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y) 
{
 return x - y;
}
```

How can I run this C code with perl using `Inline::C`? I tried but i am not exactly getting.

Comment: can you paste the code and what problem are you facing?? Is there a problem with the code you written or you don't know how to write it using inline C in perl?

Comment: Has it occured to you that perl's own add/subtract operators will also be implemented in C.  I imagine you're not saving very little (likely nothing) by doing this.  If you were implementing an algorithm in C, that'd be a different story.  Having said that, if you're just doing this as an experiment to work out how inline C works, I retract my comment ;-)

Comment: Senthil,just a suggestion, ignore writing your signature or name,it anyways will be displayed by stack overflow :)

Comment: i don no how to write code using inline function.

Comment: There are examples in the Inline::C documentation. Did you try those? Where's your program where you tried to use Inline::C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Have a look at
  [`Inline::C-Cookbook`](http://p3rl.org/Inline::C-Cookbook) - A Cornucopia of Inline C Recipes, you
  will get lot of **examples using Inline
  with C**.
- See [`Inline`](http://p3rl.org/Inline) - Write Perl subroutines in other programming languages, you will come to know how to use Inline and you will get C examples too.

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
use Inline 'C';

print "9 + 16 = ", add(9, 16), "\n";
print "9 - 16 = ", subtract(9, 16), "\n";

__END__
__C__

int add(int x, int y) {
 return x + y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y) {
 return x - y;
}
```